# Can a regular language have uncountably many strings?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, uncountability

Obviously it can have a countably infinite number of strings. (Take the language descibed by the regular expression 0* as an example.) But can a RL have uncountably many strings? I'm leaning toward no, but I can't really back it up.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are only countably many finite strings over any finite alphabet.  Given an alphabet $\Sigma = \{s_0, \dots, s_d\}$, you can associate the string $w$ with the number $1w$ written in base-$d$, giving an injection from the natural numbers to $\Sigma^*$.  (The reason we use the number $1w$ rather than $w$ is to avoid problems with, e.g., $2$, $02$, $002$, etc. all mapping to the same number.)

Comment: Plus, countability survives taking subsets.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an exact answer. There are countably many **finite** strings, but infinite strings are not countable per Cantor's diagonalization argument. What makes them non-regular? In other words, a real number 0<= x <1 can be thought of as a word from the lanugage `0.[0-9]*`, and that's uncountable.

Comment: @MSalters Regular languages are, by definition, languages of finite strings. If you want to talk about $\omega$-regular languages of infinite strings, that's a whole 'nother question. Also _a_ real number isn't uncountable: it's one thing.

Answer (score -3):

Yes,a regular language can have uncountable number of strings as a regular language can have unlimited strings by Kleene closure or sigma closure.

Comment: This is wrong link. Uncountable is not the same as infinite.